# Get JSON from url with Java in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, json

I need to parse a URL to a json for a school project in Android Studio (java). I found some code online that works for other people, but doesn't work for me. Here's the code I used (with the url containing the json)

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest("http://ineke.broeders.be/2021Android/webservice.aspx?do=getSteden", new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.result);
                for (int i = 0; i< response.length();i++){
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        int ID = jsonObject.getInt("stadID");
                        String stadNaam = jsonObject.getString("stadNaam");
                        String postcode = jsonObject.getString("postcode");
                        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "Name: " + stadNaam + " postcode: " + postcode);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: are you getting any Error in logs? have you added Internet permission in manifest file? i just copy pasted your code it works

Comment: Hi, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, just nothing is showing up in the textview. I have added internet permission.

Comment: I just added this line in my manifest file: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` It seems to be working now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking to/with a REST API? If it is so, you can have a look at Resttemplate (I use it with Spring Boot). It's an API Implementation for consuming API endpoints or communicating with them.

Here you can find more info about it: https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

Answer (score 0):

It's not compulsory you make use of volley
Here is a simpler code

```
public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
       String current = "";
     try{
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        url = new URL("http://ineke.broeders.be/2021Android/webservice.aspx?do=getSteden");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);

        int data = isr.read();
        while(data !=-1){
            current += (char) data;
            data = isr.read();
        }
        return current;

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(urlConnection !=null){
            urlConnection.disconnect();;
        }
    }
     }catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
      return current;


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
   try{
    
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(s);
    
        JSONObject jsonObject= jsonArray.getJSONObject(jsonArray);
                   int ID = jsonObject.getInt("stadID");
                    String stadNaam = jsonObject.getString("stadNaam");
                    String postcode = jsonObject.getString("postcode");
                    textView.setText(textView.getText() + "Name: " + stadNaam + " postcode: " + postcode);
            
        

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}
}

Call the class using
new GetData().execute();

It should works because it worked for me